# Accessing Print Composer Menu Items through Python?

Tags: pyqgis, print-composer

I am using the print composer plugin for map composition, I want that whenever a user exports the final map, the corner coordinates , label tittle and other attributes I want to push my database. How to I get access to the export Button ?

Comment: Please post links or code of what you've tried and where specifically you are stuck at.  A web search on "pyqgis print composer update or label update should get you started".

Comment: I have searched the web as you suggested , but it is all about using the expressions and updating the label in the print composer, What I am looking for is how to get access of the print composer events so that I can push the metadata to the database.

Comment: I'm not seeing a signal under the api for accessing the export menu button.  The current composer events signals api are located here:  https://qgis.org/api/classQgsComposition.html

Comment: Thanks for the help. looks like I have to find a work around to solve my problem!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably have to create a custom plugin for exporting and writing composer info to db.  There are many posts on this form and others for exporting images/pdf, and accessing the map items within the composer.  Here are a couple examples:

[PyQGIS: Code Scrap for Exporting a QGIS Composer to a Vector PDF](http://andyarthur.org/pyqgis-code-scrap-for-exporting-a-qgis-composer-to-a-vector-pdf.html)

Accessing composer label eg:

```
mapItem = qgis.utils.iface.activeComposers()[0].composition()
    for item in mapItem.items():
        if isinstance(item,QgsComposerLabel):
            # do something more
```